# Laravel Cashier (Stripe) - createAsStripeCustomer function throws error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with Laravel Cashier v9.0. Just installed it today.
I've updated User model and migration with additional field as stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#stripe-configuration).
The problem is, when I try to call a function `createAsStripeCustomer()` on existing User instance and I pass `$token` that is created on Android app as a parameter I get `Received unknown parameters: mCard, mCreated, mId, mLivemode, mType, mUsed...`
Is it the API version incompatibility or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A token should just be a string starting with `tok_`. It sounds like you’re trying to pass an object—or other parameters—to your PHP endpoint. Cashier doesn’t use parameters such as `mCard`, `mCreated`, `mId` etc.

Comment: I was trying to pass an array that I get as JSON from Android app.

Comment: @Zoka you should be able to extract the `token` value from the JSON and pass just that instead of the entire JSON object.

Comment: I tried to pass the token value, but then I get this Error: Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::createAsStripeCustomer() must be of the type array, string given.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/9.0/src/Billable.php

Comment: Apparently, as stated in the docs, for the version 9.0 of Cashier, createAsStripeCustomer() method only accepts options array.

Comment: What is it you’re actually trying to do? Add a card to a user?

Comment: I was trying to create stripe customer from User model instance. I solved the problem using Upgrade Guide https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/master/UPGRADE.md

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->createOrGetStripeCustomer([
        'source' =>  $token,
       
    ]);
```

Pass stripe token in source key as an array and it should work fine